# Quick sort in Python using one variable for the function input

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I know people will say this is a duplicate, but the code I found doesn't work and I have no idea how to fix it, so this not a duplicate because I'm asking how to fix MY code, not do the problem itself. Here's the code:

```
def partition(array, start, end):
  pivot = array[start]
  low = start + 1
  high = end
  while True:
    while low <= high and array[high] >= pivot:
        high = high - 1
    while low <= high and array[low] <= pivot:
       low = low + 1
    if low <= high:
      array[low], array[high] = array[high], array[low]
    else:
      break
  array[start], array[high] = array[high], array[start]
  return high
def qsort(array):
  start = min(array)
  end = max(array)
  if start >= end:
    return
  p = partition(array, start, end)
  qsort(array, start, p-1)
  qsort(array, p+1, end)
```

Everytime I try to use it, I get a crash. I made qsort a one variable function, then set the end to the max, and the start to the min. The crash I get when trying to use it says as follows:

```
qsort([1,5,1,6])
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 88, in qsort
    p = partition(array, start, end)
  File "main.py", line 73, in partition
    while low <= high and array[high] >= pivot:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know this means I exceeded the max, or had a stackoverflow (lol) but I'm not sure how to fix it in my code. Help!

Comment: `high` is too big. Please consider using a debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from logic, what i can see from your code is that your `start` and `end` are containing array values, it should be indices. `start` should be initialized as `0` and `end` as `len(array)-1`

Comment: replace `end =  max(array)` with `end = len(array)-1` and `start = min(array)` with `start = 0` in the definition of `qsort`

Comment: Well now I realized a new problem, in my code I had it recusrive cuz obviously, and it sends the 3 things, array start and end. Would I really need all of those? Because when I took them out I got no return even after adding return array

Comment: please post a separate question for this

Answer (score 0):

The code needs an entry function or a change in the calling code to use a recursive function with parameters start and end

```
def partition(array, start, end):
  pivot = array[start]
  low = start + 1
  high = end
  while True:
    while low <= high and array[high] >= pivot:
        high = high - 1
    while low <= high and array[low] <= pivot:
       low = low + 1
    if low <= high:
      array[low], array[high] = array[high], array[low]
    else:
      break
  array[start], array[high] = array[high], array[start]
  return high

def qsortr(array, start, end):          # recursive function
  if start >= end:
    return
  p = partition(array, start, end)
  qsortr(array, start, p-1)
  qsortr(array, p+1, end)

def qsort(array):                       # entry function
  qsortr(array, 0, len(array)-1);       # fix

A = [1,5,1,6]
qsort(A)
print(A)
```

alternate test code to sort 512K ints

```
import random
from time import time
# test sort
a = [random.randint(0, 2147483647) for r in xrange(512*1024)]
s = time()
qsort(a)
e = time()
print e - s

# check to see if data was sorted
f = 0
for i in range (1, len(a)):             # use xrange for python 2.x
    if(a[i-1] > a[i]):
        f = 1
        break
if(f == 0):
    print("sorted")
else:
    print("error")
```